# AWS API gateway throws 500 for almost all request

Tags: aws-api-gateway

AWS API gateway throws 500 for almost all request. <30% of the request are successful.
Execution logs shows the following error. **Are too many request (429) is shown as 500 or something else?**

```
    2022-08-26T10:04:04.561-05:00

(d2181bd4-9795-4bfc-a646-f16ed77160cd) Endpoint response headers: {Date=Fri, 26 Aug 2022 15:04:04 GMT, Content-Type=application/json, Content-Length=104, Connection=keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId=aac943ec-af03-445b-9cd4-f203b246544b, x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length=0, X-Amz-Executed-Version=$LATEST, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=root=1-6308e0e3-101cb97e2d042e573dd35c26;sampled=1}
(d2181bd4-9795-4bfc-a646-f16ed77160cd) Endpoint response headers: {Date=Fri, 26 Aug 2022 15:04:04 GMT, Content-Type=application/json, Content-Length=104, Connection=keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId=aac943ec-af03-445b-9cd4-f203b246544b, x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length=0, X-Amz-Executed-Version=$LATEST, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=root=1-6308e0e3-101cb97e2d042e573dd35c26;sampled=1}

2022-08-26T10:04:04.561-05:00

(d2181bd4-9795-4bfc-a646-f16ed77160cd) Endpoint response body before transformations: 
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": "Unable to handle request"
}
(d2181bd4-9795-4bfc-a646-f16ed77160cd) Endpoint response body before transformations: {"statusCode": 500, "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, "body": "Unable to handle request"}

2022-08-26T10:04:04.562-05:00


(d2181bd4-9795-4bfc-a646-f16ed77160cd) Method response body after transformations: Unable to handle request
(d2181bd4-9795-4bfc-a646-f16ed77160cd) Method response body after transformations: Unable to handle request
```

[image]

Comment: What is the endpoint code? I mean the endpoint will at somepoint have returned a `"statusCode": 500...` I'm assuming so what prompted that response ?

Answer (score 0):

The lambda processing the response was throwing that code for an exception scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to diagnose this without seeing the Lambda code as well ... `500` is the default internal service error when your webapp can't find the right things. Given the info that we have, that this is from AWS Lambda and API Gateway, I would check your Lambda settings and see how much memory you've given it and what the timeout is.